# Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office

I installed Microsoft Office 2010 on my new computer, but when I rebooted the computer after installation, nothing happened.  I don't see Office 2010 icons on my desktop.  I see three different files in the list of programs on my C drive that are related to Office 2010, but when I open them, all I get is a big list of files...the program won't open so I can do work.  What can I do?  I've installed the disc twice, so I'm sure the files are in my new computer, but they just won't open so I can use them.

Comment: Office doesn't automatically add icons to your desktop.  Is there not a Microsoft Office folder listed in Start -> All Programs?

Comment: @sunk818 - Office 2013 and Office 2010 were released almost 3+ years from one another.  Office 2013 also changed HOW Office was installed.

Answer (score 1):

How to create windows desktop shortcut for Office 2010 Application
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFtx5YQgrGw

Go To:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14 (or whatever the largest Officexx is)
- Right-click on WinWord.exe and select Send To > Desktop
- Repeat for any other applications such as Excel.exe, PowerPnt.exe, or MsAccess.exe

Comment: Could you please write the steps to complete this task in the question itself?